# BlueMix not starting due to health check timeout

Tags: go, ibm-cloud

I'm using Go to try create a simple 'hello world'-eque script using IBM's BlueMix. I've been able to use their hello world script which runs fine, however upon writing my own it fails.

I'm aware that you need to take the environment variable for the port, which is what I've done, however with this in place, the check is still unable to start the service.

```
package main

import (
    "io"
    "net/http"
    "log"
    "os"
    "fmt"
)

const (
    DEFAULT_PORT = "4001"
    DEFAULT_HOST = "localhost"
)

func HelloServer(w http.ResponseWriter, req *http.Request) {
    io.WriteString(w, "hello, world!\n")
}

func main() {
    http.HandleFunc("/hello", HelloServer)

    var port string
    if port = os.Getenv("VCAP_APP_PORT"); len(port) == 0 {
        port = DEFAULT_PORT
    }

    var host string
    if host = os.Getenv("VCAP_APP_HOST"); len(host) == 0 {
        host = DEFAULT_HOST
    }


    log.Printf("Using host %v+\n", host)
    log.Printf("Using port %v+\n", port)
    fmt.Println("######" + port)

    err := http.ListenAndServe(host+":"+port, nil)
    if err != nil {
        log.Printf("ListenAndServe: ", err)
    }
}
```

Any help as to why this program is failing is greatly appreciated.

-- update --

The output of `cf logs app --recent` is:

```
2015-08-13T16:47:36.36+0100 [DEA/10]     OUT Removing crash for app with id ae803621-0b84-48d2-b3fd-6067053b40a6
2015-08-13T16:47:36.36+0100 [DEA/10]     OUT Stopping app instance (index 0) with guid ae803621-0b84-48d2-b3fd-6067053b40a6
2015-08-13T16:47:36.36+0100 [DEA/10]     OUT Stopped app instance (index 0) with guid ae803621-0b84-48d2-b3fd-6067053b40a6
2015-08-13T16:53:38.29+0100 [DEA/87]     OUT Starting app instance (index 0) with guid ae803621-0b84-48d2-b3fd-6067053b40a6
2015-08-13T16:54:02.13+0100 [DEA/87]     ERR Instance (index 0) failed to start accepting connections
2015-08-13T16:54:02.18+0100 [API/0]      OUT App instance exited with guid ae803621-0b84-48d2-b3fd-6067053b40a6 payload: {"cc_partition"=>"default", "droplet"=>"ae803621-0b84-48d2-b3fd-6067053b40a6", "version"=>"2ed88562-d12c-4391-ae8f-5fd8475cc350", "instance"=>"e4f99db81d194b1bb865a9e55f0a1d54", "index"=>0, "reason"=>"CRASHED", "exit_status"=>127, "exit_description"=>"failed to accept connections within health check timeout", "crash_timestamp"=>1439481242}
2015-08-13T16:54:02.21+0100 [API/10]     OUT App instance exited with guid ae803621-0b84-48d2-b3fd-6067053b40a6 payload: {"cc_partition"=>"default", "droplet"=>"ae803621-0b84-48d2-b3fd-6067053b40a6", "version"=>"2ed88562-d12c-4391-ae8f-5fd8475cc350", "instance"=>"e4f99db81d194b1bb865a9e55f0a1d54", "index"=>0, "reason"=>"CRASHED", "exit_status"=>127, "exit_description"=>"failed to accept connections within health check timeout", "crash_timestamp"=>1439481242}
```

Comment: Have you tried looking at the logs? Using the cf cli, you can type `cf logs appName --recent`

Comment: Hi, yes, it returns: "ERR Instance (index 0) failed to start accepting connections" which leads me to believe that the port is not being set correctly?

Comment: This error can mean a number of things - essentially it's just saying your server never started. Can you post the full log output after your app finishes staging?

Comment: Updated. There's lots of repetition in the error log, so I've taken the bottom 'chunk'. If you require more, please let me know. Thanks!

Comment: I deployed your code with successful results. Can you confirm you have a `Procfile`? I recommend you download the go starter code, and replace the `app.go` with your code.

Comment: Ram, you are correct, it was indeed the procfile. How come it works with `web: gohelloworld` when nothing in the manifest or app.go references gohelloworld. Thank you for your help!

Comment: @RamVennam you should submit your comment as an answer so he can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The above program I wrote is correct and runs as it should. The issue was that the procfile was not correctly set up. The procfile blueMix uses in its example Go program is `web: gohelloworld`.

`gohelloworld` can be found in the godeps/Godeps.json file, as the `ImportPath` value. So when generating your godep file, the generated value from `ImportPath` is the value you should place in your procfile.

In my case, it should have been: `web: test`.